# Selective read/write permissions on a samba share to a windows server

Tags: windows, filesystems, nfs, samba

We have shared our file system across our ecosystem and we use samba to share it to our windows servers. The issue is that we would like the windows server to have only read permission to certain subfolders under the share. Is it even possible or is NFS better suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I am not sure if you can just create read-only NFS shares for these certain subfolders separately. You can mount the main share as R/O and then export the subfolders (separate definition in /etc/exports) which can be read and written as another share. I am not sure of this solution, but you should try this to achieve what you intend.